# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation in Chrome or SCRIPT65535: Invalid calling object in IE when submit form

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I am  getting Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation  in Chrome or SCRIPT65535: Invalid calling object in IE when submit form.

Following markup reproduces error:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Enter some text in the fields below, then press the "Submit form" button to submit the form.</p>

<form id="myForm" action="form_action.asp">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit form">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction()
{
var submit2 = myForm.submit;
submit2();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But when instead lines:

```
var submit2 = myForm.submit;
submit2();
```

Directly sumbit form myForm.submit() then all work without error.

So how to fix problem is clear for me, for me is interesting why "indirect" form submit causes errors

Comment: You're still calling `myForm.submit` without the `()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The submit method when called with `myForm.submit()` knows the context is myForm, but when we are calling it using `submit2()`, there is not context ( global context), so its giving error.**

To fix the error, you have to call the `submit2()` method by setting the content of this to the myForm.

The sample code is

```
var submit2 = myForm.submit;
submit2.call(myForm);
```

You can either use call or apply for changing the context.

More Info on call and apply:

1. [apply mdn reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)
2. [call mdn reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: Strange is that it is functioning well in IE9-10 but not in IE11, such error only appears in IE11 and Chrome. When it is problem with context, which is most likely, then is should be reproducing in IE9-10 as well